# get secondary Image and Swap on category page in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am getting issue to show the secondary images.
I need to show secondary Image code to Swap product image on category page in bigcommerce.

Please share me the code if some one do it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ProductList li:first-child img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).attr("src", "http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-pktq5q/b2aus7wd/products/88/images/460/cmpltunknwn_wolfgold_view003__18141.1396558339.1280.1280.jpg?c=1");
        })
    .mouseout(function() {
       $(this).attr("src", "http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-pktq5q/b2aus7wd/products/88/images/461/cmpltunknwn_wolfgold_view001__55714.1396558344.330.330.jpg?c=1");
    })
```

Comment: Good one helpful for me

Comment: its ok just chill

Answer (score 0):

Find the code: in templates >> components >> products >> card.html

```
<img src="{{getImage image 'productgallery_size' (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{image.alt}}" title="{{image.alt}}">
```

And insert the code below after the previous code:

```
{{#each (limit images 2)}}
{{#if @index '>' 0}} 
<img src="{{getImage this 'productgallery_size' (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{this.alt}}" title="{{this.alt}}"> 
{{/if}} 
{{/each}}
```